# how to enable unity global menu on Android Studio in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: unity, android, android-studio

I just installed android studio in ubuntu but I expected something like this:

[image]

however I have this:

[image]

what do I need for enabling unity global menu on Android Studio???

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Haven't personay try it but this is what is seems you need:

Java Swing Ayatana is a project that brings Ubuntu global menu (AppMenu) and HUD support for Java Swing applications.

JAyatana version 2 was released recently, getting support for Ubuntu 13.10 along with a PPA for easy installation. Update: the PPA now supports Ubuntu 14.04 and 14.10.

http://www.webupd8.org/2014/02/get-unity-global-menu-hud-support-for.html

Terminal:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danjaredg/jayatana
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install jayatana
```

Comment: After having used this integration for several months on two machines, I've decided to remove it again. Menus sometimes appear empty and ultimately stop appearing altogether, resulting in an internal IDE error in Android Studio.

Comment: Did not work on 16.10.